# Performance results of PageSpeed Insights change whenever I refresh the page

Tags: wordpress, performance, pagespeed

I put the URL of my website there : https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ to look up its performances. The only problem is the results keep changing, I got 97, then 89, then 93... it changes whenever I refresh the page, after one second. It never remains the same although I've made NO updates on my website. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Google explains here why this result fluctuate :

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/v3/scoring#perf-consistency

And there is lot of documents to dig deeper on this :

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/docs/variability.md